# how to get model item data in the JS in MVC 3 view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a MVC application.
I am displaying the data in index view / Table.

I have added additional check box in the last column.
when user click on that check box, I want to get the value form the specific column of that selected/checked row.

I am trying to display that value in the JS's alert window but it not displaying.

How to do that.

```
 @model PagedList.IPagedList<PaymentAdviceEntity.PaymentAdvice>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Company
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Amount
                    </th>
               </tr>

         @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount,"sAmount","sAmount")
                        </td>
                        <td>

    @Html.CheckBox("IsPaid", (bool)item.IsPaid, new { @value=item.Id,@class="IsPaid-"+item.Id})

                   </td>
                    </tr>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

           $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {

                if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                {
                    var nPaid = $("#sAmount").val();
                    alert(nPaid);
                }

               });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap js code to document ready.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function(){
         //TO DO smt
         });
       });
    </script>
```

And you need use different `id` in `foreach`. For example

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount, string.Format("sAmount{0}", item.Id),"sAmount")
```

or change you jquery selector using $(this).parent...

All code will be:

```
  @model PagedList.IPagedList<PaymentAdviceEntity.PaymentAdvice>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Company
                </th>
                <th>
                   Amount
                </th>
           </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.Name)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SanctionedAmount,"sAmount",new {id = string.Format("sAmount{0}", item.Id)})
                    </td>


                    <td>

@Html.CheckBox("IsPaid", (bool)item.IsPaid, new { @value=item.Id,@class="IsPaid-"+item.Id})


                 </td>
                </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var v = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            var s = 1;
            var nPaid = $("#sAmount" + v).val();
            alert(nPaid);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: First of all wrap your code to jquery document ready block. Then do alert and you will be know working script or not. `$(document).ready(function(){ alert(''); });

Comment: where should I put, I dont want to make alert on document.ready function...I want on clicked/checked event of check box.

Comment: Above I wrote code. Put it into block <script></script>. And check does it work. Did you include reference to jquery file? Open firebug (or console in google chrome) and check for errors.